# Given that matrix $C$ is invertible and $A=CBC^{-1}$, prove that if $A$ is invertible then $B$ is also invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

So far, my working proof is just a basic implication.

**Proof:** Matrix $A$ invertible implies that there exists a matrix $D$ such that $DCBC^{-1}=I$

I was thinking that I could use the associativity property to prove my result, but I'm not sure how, since $B$ is in between $C$ and $C^{-1}$.

Comment: You could always try solving things for $B$, representing it as a composition of invertible transformations.

Comment: Just note that this says that $A$ and $B$ are similar which means the eigenvalues of $B$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A$ and which is why $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More straight forward:

$I = C^{-1}C = C^{-1}IC = C^{-1}AA^{-1}C = C^{-1}CBC^{-1}A^{-1}C = B C^{-1}A^{-1}C = B(C^{-1}A^{-1}C)$

And similarily:

$I = C^{-1}A^{-1}AC = C^{-1}A^{-1}CBC^{-1}C = (C^{-1}A^{-1}C)B$

That is $C^{-1}A^{-1}C$ is the inverse of $B$

Answer (score 2):

An easier proof is to use the following facts about determinants:

> For square matrices $A$ and $B$
>   $$\det(A) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow A~ \text{is invertible}$$
>   $$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$

and also

> For an invertible matrix $C$
>   $$\det(C^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(C)}$$

Now, if $A$ is invertible, then $\det(A)\neq 0$

Look at the determinant of the RHS now.  $\det(CBC^{-1})=\det(C)\det(B)\det(C^{-1})$

What can you conclude about $\det(B)$?

---

For an alternate proof, if you have $A=CBC^{-1}$ then that implies that $B=C^{-1}AC$.

Now, noting that since $A$ is invertible, $A^{-1}$ exists.  Multiplying both sides of the equation on the right by $C^{-1}A^{-1}C$ gives...

Now, use the definition of what it means to be invertible (that there exists a matrix called *the inverse* such that when multiplied by will produce the identity)

Answer (score 1):

$$A=CBC^{-1}$$
$$\implies B = C^{-1}AC$$

As each of the component of $B$ is invertable, so $B$ is also invertiable.